# python for loop is only returning first index item

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

As titles says everything i also looked over some stackoverflow same question but i was not able to find the solution
**Here is my codes**

```
r = requests.get("http://cpaleaks.com", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; 
Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all = soup.find_all("div",{"id":"content"})

all[0].find_all("h2")[0].text

for item in all:
    print(item.find_all("h2")[0].text)
```

**Output**

```
6 Untapped Traffic Sources in 2019 That Convert With ANY Niche
```

**Expected Output**

> Must be all titles of website

Comment: There is most likely just one `div` with the id "content". You're looping over that single `div` and printing the text of its first "h2". (What do you expect `all[0].find_all("h2")[0].text` to accomplish on its own?)

Comment: I went to the website and looked at the page source. There is indeed only one ```div``` with ```content``` as the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how beautifulsoup works but maybe try using this code instead of the for you have at the end.

```
for h2 in all[0].find_all("h2")
    print(h2.text)
```

Comment: Thanks its working too

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

`find_all("div",{"id":"content"})` will give you a result set in your case of one `<div>` and its inner element tree, so you iterat only one time and print this one time only the text of first `<h2>`

```
print(item.find_all("h2")[0].text)
```

#### How to fix?

Iterate over first element in result set while `find_all('h2')`:

```
for item in all[0].find_all("h2")
    print(item.text)
```

or in my opinion more specific and cleaner solution, iterate over the selection of all `<h2>` in the element (div) with id content:

```
for item in soup.select('#content h2'):
    print(item.text.strip())
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get("http://cpaleaks.com", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

for item in soup.select('#content h2'):
    print(item.text.strip())
```

#### Output

```
6 Untapped Traffic Sources in 2019 That Convert With ANY Niche
3 SECRET Steps to Make Money on Instagram WITHOUT Followers – Fast & Efficient
Facebook Marketing in 2019 – SMART Strategies + Case Study!
Rank Local Businesses on the FIRST page of Google – Profit from NOOBS like a PRO!
Reddit is STILL Endless Source Of FREE Marketing Traffic – IF DONE RIGHT!
How To EXPLODE Your Earnings With HOT Targeted Pins on Pinterest
The Key In the LIST! Grow Your Subscriber Count Super FAST – Build Your Money Making MACHINE!
How to Monetize Virtual Businesses on Groupon and Make Up To $100K THIS YEAR
Laser Targeted Quora Strategy to Profit With Clickbank Products – QUORA DONE RIGHT!
```

Comment: Thanks man you saved my day <3 And thanks for explaining in details